# Can bigger exchanges act as a proxy wallet to smaller exchanges

Tags: cryptography, coinbase-api, cryptocurrency, binance-api-client

is there chance that  Coinbase or any wallet can be used as a proxy wallet i.e a smaller exchange stores its retail clients assets on Coinbase custody but when withdrawals are made by a retail client it is processed by an api and sent from custody directly to the clients wallet

can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Complex, but anything is possible. You can program a login system, and depending on who logs in, a different function in the code is executed, and the books of each client's amounts would also have to be kept and integrated into the code, and the client must not have access to alter the core coding. Maybe use python?

Answer (score -1):

You can already use Coinbase's API to make withdrawals to a wallet. Withdrawals via API exist for most exchanges.

https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#withdrawals

https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/?python#list-withdrawals

Comment: I think the question should be closed if further answers are no longer welcomed, rather than down voting answers.